# Django Query - Sort by Tags in common

Tags: python, django, django-models

As a quick example, let's say I have a Product class

```
class Product(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag',blank=True,null=True)
```

My Tag class looks like this

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, db_index=True)
```

Given one product, how would I sort a result set of all other products by most common tags?

For example I have the following:

P1 with tags A, B, and C
P2 with tags B, C
P3 with tags B
P4 with tags A, B, and C

I would want my result set for P1 to be P4, P2, P3 in that order, assuming we are excluding P1 from the result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a typical self-join usage, the SQL looks like:

```
SELECT t3.*, count(t2.tag_id) as similar_tags_count
FROM m2m_tbl t1 INNER JOIN m2m_tbl t2 
     ON (t1.tag_id = t2.tag_id and t1.product_id != t2.product_id and t1.product_id = pk_of_the_given_product)
     INNER JOIN product_tbl t3 ON (t2.product_id = t3.id)
GROUP BY t3.id, t3.name
ORDER BY similar_tags_count DESC;
```

Then the query could be feed to [`.raw()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries):

```
Product.objects.raw("""
SELECT t3.*, count(t2.tag_id) as similar_tags_count
FROM {m2m_tbl} t1 INNER JOIN {m2m_tbl} t2 
     ON (t1.tag_id = t2.tag_id and t1.product_id != t2.product_id and t1.product_id = %s)
     INNER JOIN {product_tbl} t3 ON (t2.product_id = t3.id)
GROUP BY t3.id, t3.name
ORDER BY similar_tags_count DESC;
""".format(m2m_tbl=Product.tags.through._meta.db_table, product_tbl=Product._meta.db_table),
    [the_given_product.pk])
```

Or use UNDOCUMENTED [`query.join()`](http://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2009/09/28/custom-joins-with-djangos-queryjoin/) (also [in the docstring of the `query.join()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.4.x/django/db/models/sql/query.py#L851)) to handle the join if you REALLY need a `QuerySet`:

```
m2m_tbl = Product.tags.through._meta.db_table
qs = Product.objects.exclude(pk=the_given_product.pk)
alias_1 = qs.query.get_initial_alias()
alias_2 = qs.query.join((alias_1, m2m_tbl, 'id', 'product_id'))
alias_3 = qs.query.join((alias_2, m2m_tbl, 'tag_id', 'tag_id'))
qs = qs.annotate(similar_tags_count=models.Count('tags__id')).extra(where=[
    '{alias_2}.product_id != {alias_3}.product_id'.format(alias_2=alias_2, alias_3=alias_3),
    '{alias_3}.product_id = %s'.format(alias_3=alias_3)
], params=[the_given_product.pk])
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the both turns lists you can do something like so

```
P1 = ['A', 'B', 'C'] # these being products
P3 = ['B']
P4 = ['A', 'B', 'C']

P1 = set(P1)
P3_INTERSECT = len(P1.intersection(P3))
P4_INTERSECT = len(P1.intersection(P4))
```

Those will each return 1 and 3 respectively, I would then use that to order your results. If you end up needing to do this you might want to define your own manager for doing this ordering.

Comment: I slightly adjusted the wording to my question, as I believe I had improperly described my problem. My apologies.

Comment: As you can see  from my example above; what you would need to do is get the matching tags in a list, and compare them to p1 for example and order them by the number contained in common. I have updated my answer to reflect you newly revised question.

Comment: I'm not sure if this method would scale well for large result sets. Am I wrong here?