# How to manufacture Django ORM QueySet from existing data / get back to ORM queries from plain SQL?

Tags: python, sql, django, orm, django-queryset

My case:
In one place of my Django app I decided to use plain SQL, for optimization purpose - I was need a complex join, and Django ORM does not capable do such job. But use of plain SQL caused another problem - this function preferably should return a QuerySet object, and it is become impossible.

And so Im wonder - is there any approaches for constructing QuerySets manually?

Comment: As MattH suggested, `RawQuerySet` by `qs.raw()` is good option. Constructing `QuerySets` manually looks like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14993766/django-query-sort-by-tags-in-common/14997722#14997722), its undocumented and hard to write and read, do it as a last resort..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two approaches immediately available.

1. [`QuerySet.extra`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra)
   allows you to specify additional SQL.
2. [`Manager.raw`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#mapping-query-fields-to-model-fields) allows you to write a raw sql query that will expect to be mapped to model objects.